# Value of type 'PostModel.Type' has no subscripts swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Im not too sure why its giving me the error "Value of type 'PostModel.Type' has no subscripts"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFrCT.png)
.

```
class Universalchatcontroller: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

  let transition = slide()
  var tableview : UITableView!      
  var postsdata = [PostModel]()

   // var ref :  DatabaseReference!
  //  var databaseHandle : DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("mainviewdidload")

            //LOOK  HERE  RAYMOND
            //Building a News Feed w/ AutoLayout Constraints - Swift & Firebase Part 4 (youtube)
            tableview = UITableView(frame:view.bounds,style: .plain)
            //tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            view.addSubview(tableview)

            var layoutguide : UILayoutGuide!
            layoutguide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

            let cellNib = UINib(nibName:"POSTTableViewCell" , bundle: nil)
            tableview.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postcell")       
            tableview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            tableview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutguide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableview.delegate = self
            tableview.dataSource = self

            observePosts()
            tableview.reloadData()
         }

    func observePosts() {

        let postref = Database.database().reference().child("moreposts?")
        var tempPost = [PostModel]()

        postref.observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict =  childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any],
                    let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                    let uid = author[Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid],
                    let text = dict["text"]as? String,
                    let username = author[(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)!] as? String {

                    let raymond  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
                    let postMODEL = PostModel(id: childSnapshot.key, author: raymond!, text: text)
                    tempPost.append(postMODEL)

                }
            }
        })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postsdata.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! POSTTableViewCell

        cell.set(post: PostModel[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: What is `PostModel`? And I think you have to write it as `postsdata[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Should you not be using postsdata[indexPath.row] ?

Answer (score 1):

try and use the same data source object.

```
cell.set(post: PostModel[indexPath.row])
```

To

```
cell.set(post: postsdata[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign array of `PostModel` replace

```
cell.set(post: PostModel[indexPath.row])
```

with

```
cell.set(post: postsdata[indexPath.row])
```

And from you code in `observePosts()` add data to `postsdata` or declare `tempPost` globally and use that array in `cellForRowAt`